# Strange PHP redirect behavior - All if statements work fine, while the else statement overrides and becomes the default redirect

Tags: php, redirect, http-status-code-301, if-statement

I have a quick question that should be simple for most people here. On a website, I am redirecting all my links through 1 simple PHP redirect called visit.php

I am formatting my outbound redirects like this..

```
visit.php?url=google.com
visit.php?url=yahoo.com
visit.php?url=aol.com
```

Then my visit.php looks like this...

```
<?php
$url = htmlspecialchars($_GET['url']);

if($url == 'google.com'){
header("Location: http://google.com");
}

if($url == 'yahoo.com'){
header("Location: http://yahoo.com");
}

if($url == 'aol.com'){
header("Location: http://aol.com");
}

else {
header("Location: http://mydomain.com/404");
}
```

The problem I am having is with the else statement. When I delete it from the script, everything works as expected. When I put it in (so any misspellings redirect to a 404) it overrides all the links I defined in the script and redirects to the 404.

Another problem I am having is when the ?url= variable is not used. If a user on my site copies the link to their clipboard and changes it to anything but ?url= I'd like to redirect to the 404. The code I have tried using to accomplish this looks like this...

```
if(!isset($_GET['url'])){
header("Location: http://mydomain.com/404");
}
```

My logic is... if the ?url= variable is not set, just redirect to 404 because someone must be playing around. If somebody loads visit.php?id=blah it should just redirect to the 404.

However, I am not getting the expected behavior. I am pretty new to PHP and programming in general... so forgive me if these questions are kindergarten level. Thanks.

Comment: If $url = google, executes location goodle, because this is valid, doesn't execute location yahoo, because invalid, doesn't execute location aol because invalid; but because last is invalid it does execute the else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using the `if`/`else if`/`else` construct otherwise that else statement is attached only to the last `if`.

When the condition of that last `if` is not fulfilled it'll naturally execute the `else` clause.

### Your initial approach (corrected):

```
<?php
$url = htmlspecialchars($_GET['url']);

if($url == 'google.com'){
    header("Location: http://google.com");
}

else if($url == 'yahoo.com'){
    header("Location: http://yahoo.com");
}

else if($url == 'aol.com'){
    header("Location: http://aol.com");
}

else {
    header("Location: http://mydomain.com/404");
}
```

### Usual approach:

```
    <?php
$url = htmlspecialchars($_GET['url']);

if($url == 'google.com'){
    header("Location: http://google.com");
    exit;
}

if($url == 'yahoo.com'){
    header("Location: http://yahoo.com");
    exit;
}

if($url == 'aol.com'){
    header("Location: http://aol.com");
    exit;
}

header("Location: http://mydomain.com/404");
exit;
```

### Best (recommended) approach:

```
switch($url) {
    case 'google.com':
        header("Location: http://google.com");
        break;
    case 'yahoo.com':
        header("Location: http://yahoo.com");
        break;
    case 'aol.com':
        header("Location: http://aol.com");
        break;
    default:
        header("Location: http://mydomain.com/404");
        break;
}
```

### Hmmm... better yet:

```
$list_of_places = array(
    'google.com',
    'yahoo.com',
    'aol.com'
);

if(in_array($url, $list_of_places)) {
    header("Location: http://".$url);
    exit;
}
else {
    header("Location: http://mydomain.com/404");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: That is awesome, thank you! The last issue I am having is if somebody decides to change visit.php?url=google.com to a different key like visit.php?haha=blah ... the way my code is written now it doesn't redirect to the 404... I get a nasty PHP error. My if(!isset($_GET['url'])) code does not work as I'd expect.

Comment: All of the examples I wrote work even in the case when `$_GET['url'] == NULL` (which is what happens when it's not defined).

Answer (score 3):

The code continues to execute after you issue `header('Location: ...')`. Subsequent headers overwrite previously set headers. You need to *stop code execution* if you do not want to do anything further:

```
header(...);
exit;
```

Also, the `else` only applies to the last `if`, since the statements are not linked together.

Answer (score 2):

it should be

```
<?php
$url = htmlspecialchars($_GET['url']);

if($url == 'google.com'){
header("Location: http://google.com");
}

else if($url == 'yahoo.com'){
header("Location: http://yahoo.com");
}

else if($url == 'aol.com'){
header("Location: http://aol.com");
}

else {
header("Location: http://mydomain.com/404");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

As a lazy programmer I recommand rewriting your code to

```
   $url = htmlspecialchars(!empty($_GET['url'])?$_GET['url']:"");

    switch($url)
    {

      case 'google.com': 
         header("Location: http://google.com");
         break;
      case 'yahoo.com': 
         header("Location: http://yahoo.com");
         break;
      case 'aol.com': 
         header("Location: http://aol.com");
         break;
      default:
         header("Location: http://mydomain.com/404");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Either use `if else` instead if just `if` (because you are executing that last 'else' statement):

```
<?php
    $url = htmlspecialchars($_GET['url']);
    if($url == 'google.com'){
        header("Location: http://google.com");
    } else if ($url == 'yahoo.com') {
        header("Location: http://yahoo.com");
    } else if ($url == 'aol.com'){
        header("Location: http://aol.com");
    } else {
        header("Location: http://mydomain.com/404");
    }
?>
```

Or use a switch statement:

```
<?php
    $url = htmlspecialchars($_GET['url']);
    switch ($url) {
        case 'google.com':
            header("Location: http://google.com");
            break;
        case 'yahoo.com':
            header("Location: http://yahoo.com");
            break;
        case 'aol.com':
            header("Location: http://aol.com");
            break;
        default:
            header("Location: http://mydomain.com/404");
    }
?>
```

With either of these solutions, if your `$url` does not equal what you want it to equal the user will be directed to your 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out the "redirect to 404 if a different key is attempted" problem (simply added the error control operator in the first declaration).

My code now looks like this...

```
<?php

$url = @htmlspecialchars($_GET['url']);

if(!isset($_GET['url'])){
header("Location: http://mydomain.com/404");
exit;
}

elseif($url == 'google.com'){
header("Location: http://google.com");
exit;
}

elseif($url == 'yahoo.com'){
header("Location: http://yahoo.com");
exit;
}

elseif($url == 'aol.com'){
header("Location: http://aol.com");
exit;
}

else{
header("Location: http://mydomain.com/404");
exit;
}
```